# Matlab uint8 sparse

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

When creating a sparse matrix in Matlab it seems that you can create a sparse matrix either filled with logicals or double valued numbers.

While reading around I understood that Matlab does not have support for other type of sparse matrices, i.e. `uint8` or other integers. In my application I know that `max(values)==16`, and the memory is a crucial thing, therefore I would like to have `uint8` sparse matrices.

- Is there a way of creating a `unit8` sparse matrix?
- If not (most likely), is there any apparent reason of why Matlab has not implemented `uint8` sparse matrices?

Comment: What sorts of operations are you going to want to do on this matrix?

Comment: Multiplication mainly,  but some others also.  The is for Iterative algebraic reconstruction techniques in tomographic applications. The use of sparse matrices is quite common there.  @beaker

Comment: So implementing your own replacement would not be trivial ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see how using `uint8` instead of a `double` would be no or little improvement.

A dense matrix is a continuous array so no extra indexing or structuring is required, the position of each element is given by its physical location in the memory.

But a sparse matrix should additionally require to store each element index, which in case of a 2D matrix would be two integers 32 or 64 bits in size to remember each element row and column number. On top of that there might be some implementation related overhead, such as a tree structure, or something else, used to make sparse matrix operations efficient.

So it is not 8 `uint8` vs 64 `double`, eight times more less memory usage, but rather  (8+32+32+log(n)+..) vs (64+32+32+log(n)+..), which i guess might end up being 10-20% savings at the best?

Furthermore each memory address now stores 64 bits if I remember correctly, which is one `double` or 8 `uint8` packed together. This means a few extra bits needs to be used per entry just to remember which `uint8` packed at that memory address we need, and adds some extra bit masking operations to perform.

So the guys at Mathworks probably did similar estimate, and decided to just do `double` sparse matrices.

Comment: Hum I see, that makes sense. However my matrix is 1.5GB when on RAM, so absolutely any improvement would have been welcome. Thanks for the insight though!

Comment: Note that Matlabs matrices are not "fully-sparse". Only the column index is stored for each element  (Can be checked easily by: X=sparse(1,10000); whos X; ). Thus, your computation changes to 8+32+log(n).. vs 64+32+log(n)... .