# Converting matlab sparse matrix to single precision

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I want to convert a sparse matrix in matlab to single precision, however it appears that matlab doesn't have single sparse implemented.

Instead of that, I am just planning on checking it the values are outside of the single precision range and rounding them off to the highest and lowest values of the single precision range.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
for i = 1:rows
    for j = 1:cols
        if (abs(A(i,j) < 2^-126))
            A(i,j) == 0;
        end
    end
end
```

However, ths is extremely slow. Is there another command I can use that will work on sparse matrix class type in MATLAB? I notice most commands don't work for the sparse data type.

EDIT 1:

I also tried the following, but as you can see I run out of memory (the matrix is sparse and is 200K x 200K with ~3 million nonzeros):

```
A(A < 2^-126) = 0
Error using  < 
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

EDIT 2:

Current solution I developed based on input from @rahnema1:

```
% Convert entries that aren't in single precision
idx = find(A); % find locations of nonzeros
idx2 = find(abs(A(idx)) < double(realmin('single')));
A(idx(idx2)) = sign(A(idx(idx2)))*double(realmin('single'));
idx3 = find(abs(Problem.A(idx)) > double(realmax('single')));
A(idx(idx3)) = sign(A(idx(idx3)))*double(realmax('single'));
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894231/matlab-uint8-sparse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find indices of non zero elements and use that to change the matrix;

```
idx = find(A);
Anz = A(idx);
idx = idx(Anz < 2^-126);
A(idx) = 0;
```

Or more compact:

```
idx = find(A);
A(idx(A(idx) < 2^-126)) = 0;
```

However if you want to convert from double to single you can use `single` function:

```
idx = find(A); 
A(idx) = double(single(full(A(idx))));
```

or

```
A(find(A)) = double(single(nonzeros(A)));
```

To convert `Inf` to `realmax` you can write:

```
A(find(A)) = double(max(-realmax('single'),min(realmax('single'),single(nonzeros(A)))));
```

If you only  want to convert Inf to realmax you can do:

```
Anz = nonzeros(A);
AInf = isinf(A);
Anz(AInf) = double(realmax('single')) * sign(Anz(AInf));
A(find(A)) = Anz;
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this:    idx = find(A);

A(idx(abs(A(idx)) < double(realmin('single')))) = sign(idx(A(idx) < double(realmin('single'))))*-1;

but it's taking a long time

Comment: If you want to convert double to single have you tried `idx = find(A); A(idx) = single(A(idx));` ?

Comment: yes, the result of that command is the following: Error using single
Attempt to convert to unimplemented sparse type

Comment: yes. see my answer too. I didn't like how values greater than realmax('single') got converted to infinity, then they are basically unusable in any computations, which for my purposes isn't what I desired

Answer (score 0):

As one still reaches this thread when interested in how to convert sparse to single: an easy answer is to use `full()`. However, this can be problematic if you rely on the memory savings that sparse gives you, as it basically converts to double first.

```
sparseMatrix = sparse(ones(2, 'double'));
single(full(sparseMatrix)) % works
% ans =
%  2×2 single matrix
%     1     1
%     1     1
single(sparseMatrix) % doesn't work
% Error using single
% Attempt to convert to unimplemented sparse type
```